# StringTokenizer, JSON and comma's

Tags: java, android, json, stringtokenizer

I have a problem reading in strings with comma's within a JSON object within my Android project. A working JSON string is below:

```
{"success": "[TG2301_Stoke Holy Cross, TF7439_Thornham Corner, TL8583_Thetford]"}
```

But sometimes the place names have comma's, and that throws a wobbly with the JSON and StringTokenizer methods that I use to parse the JSON into key:values pairs, as shown below in last entry:

```
{"success": "[TG2301_Stoke Holy Cross, TF7439_Thornham Corner, TL8583_Thetford, North]"}
```

Before I found this bug I was using the following to parse the JSON:

```
StringTokenizer str1 = new StringTokenizer(str,"[,]");
while (str1.hasMoreTokens()) {
String val = str1.nextToken().trim();
// Split the string at the underscore and do some stuff
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to properly escape the comma within the placename string, either in the Java when creating the JSON, or within the StringTokenizer? Thanks.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON. `success` looks like an array of strings but strings are supposed to be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: If I put my 'good' JSON string into http://jsonlint.com/ it comes back as valid.

Comment: Just because it's syntactically valid it doesn't mean it does what you want. Oh, how much easier life would be then (or possibly not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anyone suggest how to properly escape the comma within the placename string, either in the Java when creating the JSON *[...]* ?

Your problem is that you're return many values as a single string - you've got the double quotes *outside* the brackets, rather than inside (enclosing the individual values). You probably want to usa a JSON list of strings instead of chopping stuff up yourself:

```
{"success": ["TG2301_Stoke Holy Cross", 
             "TF7439_Thornham Corner", 
             "TL8583_Thetford, North"]}
```

This way, the commas within quotes aren't magical in any way, and you get your place names as nice strings.

Having said that, what you *actually* want to do is return a JSON object (which works much like a Java dictionary) instead of a list of strings, so that you even get your key/value pairs split up nicely:

```
{"success": {"TG2301": "Stoke Holy Cross", 
             "TF7439": "Thornham Corner", 
             "TL8583": "Thetford, North"}}
```

Comment: OK, I'm sure I can create this, but what StringTokenizer 'tokens' would you use to parse this? Comma would surely have the same issues?

Comment: Forget last comment - I can see you are suggesting JSON objects instead of a single string. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the approach of placing the double quotes inside the brackets - what if part of the string itself contains double quotes?

Comment: @BornToCode you escape them, just like in Java or JavaScript (or any C-derived language): `"this string contains \"double quotes\""`